# $f$ is a fixed-point of $h$. $\Theta h$ is also a fixed-point of $h$. Can we conclude that $f$ equals $\Theta h$?

Tags: lambda-calculus, fixed-points

I’m following along to a derivation of the function that returns the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers in this brilliant.org [article on Lambda Calculus](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/). To get to the derivation, either

- Go to **Fixed Points and Recursion** section > **Recursion** subsection > the first **Example** in that subsection.
- Or, if it is collapsed, expand the **Fixed Points and Recursion** section, then search (`Ctrl-F` or `Cmd-F`) for the following

  > Let us try to implement a function that returns the sum of the first

It seems to me like they make the following argument:

1. $f$ is a fixed point of some function $h$, i.e. $f = hf$. (See footnote $^1$)
2. Hey, you know what else is a fixed-point of $h$? ($\Theta h$) is a fixed-point of $h$ (where $\Theta$ is Turing’s fixed-point combinator)
3. Conclude from `1.` and `2.` that $f = \Theta h$.

I’m wondering if that’s a valid conclusion. It seems like it doesn’t necessarily have to follow from the premises (`1.` and `2.`). It seems to assume something - it seems to assume either:

- $h$ has only one fixed-point, so if we find two things that are each a fixed-point of $h$, then the two things must be the same thing, or
- more strongly, that all fixed-points of a function $h$ are equal to each other.

---

$^1$: In the article’s derivation, $h$ is

$$(\lambda g. \lambda n.\textsf{ifThenElse}\ (\textsf{isZero}\ n)\ \bar 0\ (\textsf{add}\ n\ (g\ (\textsf{pred}\ n))))$$

where $\textsf{ifThenElse}$, $\textsf{isZero}$, $\textsf{add}$, and $\textsf{pred}$ are functions defined earlier in the article.

Comment: I don't find your quoted section starting from "We've established that f is a fixed point of" in your linked source, can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry about that. I clarified. Should I transcribe their derivation here?

Comment: Notation: if f as point then g denotes a functional?
Don't see a context free base for a fixpoint being unique. May there are some constraints in "Lambda Calculus".

Comment: @SamGinrich both $f$ and $g$ (note: after latest edit, I renamed $g$ to $h$) are functions. There are no constraints AFAIK regarding the number of fixed points a function can have in $\lambda$-calculus. For example, every point (really every function since everything is a function in $\lambda$-calculus) is a fixed-point of the identity function $I = \lambda x.x$ because $If = f$ for all $f$.

Comment: @SamGinrich $fh$ means apply $f$ to $h$ or in some sense “evaluate $f$ with $h$ as the input to $f$”.

Comment: It's definitely not unique, see also nlab article on same topic with a similar concrete example [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fixed-point+combinator#)...

Comment: @mohottnad thanks! I followed the “nfab” link. It’s not as explicit, but the underlying argument is the same as you said. For completeness, in this case, $$h = \textsf{genfact} = \lambda gn.\textsf{ifElseThen}\ (\textsf{isZero}\ n)\ \bar 1\ (\textsf{mul}\ n\ (g\ (\textsf{pred}\ n)))$$

We also have $f = \textsf{fact}$. The rest is the same: $f = hf$ which has a solution $f = Yf$.

Comment: This article contains nothing new and I only referenced for confirmation evidence in case you're not completely certain, since now seems you completely understand you don't need it any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your referenced section from "Let us try to implement a function that returns the sum of the first", there's no principle issue as it's a standard application of fixed point combinators in untyped lambda calculus and functional programming. And you're absolutely right we find our named function $f$ now becomes a fixed point of the lambda abstraction $h=λg.λn.ifThenElse(isZero~n) \overline 0 (add~n(g(pred~n)))$, and we also know for any untyped lambda expression $h$ we always have some fixed point combinator $\Theta$ such that $\Theta h$ is a fixed point of $h$. So we have $f=hf, \Theta h=h \Theta h$, then we can obviously have $f=\Theta h$ as a possible solution for $f$. But by no means it's *the* only solution since as you said $h$ has many other famous combinators like $Y$ (actually infinitely many combinators per wikipedea source Bimbó, Katalin (27 July 2011). Combinatory Logic: Pure, Applied and Typed. p. 48. ISBN 9781439800010.). We may as well have $f=Yh$ since $Yh$ is also such a famous alternative fixed point of $h$. But whatever form we have we've already successfully applied fixed point combinator to transform the named recursive function $f$ to an equivalent lambda function $\Theta h$ (or $Yh$, etc), and the next section in your ref you see a concrete Haskell implementation of it.

So in summary your reference here is somewhat confusing by not mentioning this result is not unique...

Comment: Thanks! Phrasing it as “f = $\Theta h$ is a solution (but not necessarily the only solution) to $f = hf$“ really helped me understand the situation. So $f = hf$ Is a constraint, but does not necessarily uniquely define $f$. It just says that if $f$ exists, then it must be a fixed-point of $h$.